# Как получить значение переменной из экземпляра класса

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс

```
public class OwnerWrite {
    public static int Session { get; set; }
    public static string Content { get; set;  }
    public OwnerWrite(int _session, string _content) {
        Session = _session;
        Content = _content;
    }
}
```

В ходе выполнения создаётся экземпляр `list.Add(new OwnerWrite(5, "test"));`

Я попытался получить `Сontent` (в главном классе) вот так:

```
var _list = list.ToArray();
Console.Write(list[0].Content);
```

Но это естественно не сработало. Как победить?

Comment: убрать `static`. Либо обращаться через класс `OwnerWrite.Content`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае неверное использование ключевого слова [static](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

При использовании данного ключевого слова, поле объявляется на уровне *класса*, а не экземпляра.

Обращаться к таким полям нужно через имя класса: `OwnerWrite.Content`.

Так как в данном случае значения этих полей заполняются в конструкторе, для решения проблемы достаточно убрать `static` из определения и код заработает:

```
public class OwnerWrite {
    public int Session { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set;  }
    public OwnerWrite(int _session, string _content) {
        Session = _session;
        Content = _content;
    }
}

...

list.Add(new OwnerWrite(5, "test"));
Console.Write(list[0].Content); // test
```